# IoTEdge VisualStudio Code: "useradd" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, azure-iot-edge

I am developing IoTEdge module in VisualStudio Code and following [This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module). While using the option

> Build IoT Edge Solution

[image: Build IoT Edge Solution]

i am getting the error at step 10

```
useradd is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

[image: useradd error]

OS: Windows10

Comment: Is your Docker running in Windows container mode or Linux container mode? If the former, please update `${MODULES.modulename.amd64}` in your deployment.template.json to `${MODULES.modulename.windows-amd64}`

Comment: Thanks man, this solved the issue. post it as an answer so that i would accept it.

Comment: @Bilah Posted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Docker is running in Windows container mode. Please update `${MODULES.modulename.amd64}` in your deployment.template.json to `${MODULES.modulename.windows-amd64}`.